# Update a fragment using broadcast receiver

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver

im trying to build a step-counter app using Android Studio. I created a fragment "Home Fragment" with and inner class "MyService" where i selected my sensor "TYPE_STEP_COUNTER" and sending on my BroadcastReceiver the var step. Then i want to update the layout inflated on fragment but the ways i tryed doesn't work. here the code:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    //public static final String STEP_COUNT_UPDATE = "com.example.StayFit.STEP_COUNT_UPDATE";
    public static final String STAY_FIT = "com.example.stayfit";
    private static final int UPDATE_PROGRESS_BAR = 1;

    LocalBroadcastReceiver localtReceiver;
    IntentFilter intentFilter;
    DataBaseHandler dbHandler;
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefSC;

    TextView mTextViewKMPercorsi;
    TextView mTextObiettivoPassi;
    TextView mTextPassiRimanenti;
    CircularProgressIndicator circularProgress;
   
    private int obiettivoPassi;
    private String obiettivoPassiStr;
    private boolean isRegistered = false;
    Handler mHandler;   // Metodo 4
    public float lunghezzaPassi;
    private String lunghezzaPassiStr;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Recupero l'utente della sessione attraverso SP per ottenere l'obiettivo passi.
        sharedPrefSC = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(STAY_FIT, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String nomeUtente = sharedPrefSC.getString("utenteSessione", "fail");
        //Log.d("SHAREDPREF","viene passato" + nomeUtente);

        // Recupero l'obiettivo passi dal DB
        dbHandler = new DataBaseHandler(getActivity());
        obiettivoPassi = dbHandler.getObiettivoPassi(nomeUtente);
        obiettivoPassiStr = Integer.toString(obiettivoPassi);

        Intent service = new Intent(getActivity(), StepService.class);
        getActivity().startService(service);

        // Metodo 4 - handler
        mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message message) {
                if (message.what == UPDATE_PROGRESS_BAR) {
                    // Aggiorna la progress bar
                    int progress = message.arg1;;
                    circularProgress.setCurrentProgress(progress);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Looper Corretto", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mTextViewKMPercorsi.setText((String) message.obj + " Km");
                    mTextPassiRimanenti.setText("Forza! Ti mancano ancora " + message.arg2 + " passi per il tuo obiettivo!");
                }
            }
        };


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Faccio l'inflate del layout per questo fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        circularProgress = v.findViewById(R.id.circular_progress);
        mTextViewKMPercorsi = v.findViewById(R.id.textViewKMPercorsi);
        mTextObiettivoPassi = v.findViewById(R.id.textObiettivoPassi);
        mTextPassiRimanenti = v.findViewById(R.id.textPassiRimanenti);

        mTextObiettivoPassi.setText("Obiettivo passi pls: " + obiettivoPassiStr);

        circularProgress.setMaxProgress(obiettivoPassi);
        //circularProgress.setCurrentProgress(conteggioPassiTotali);

        // Procedo a registrare il BroadCast Receiver:
        intentFilter = new IntentFilter(LocalBroadcastReceiver.STEP_COUNT_UPDATE);
        localtReceiver = new LocalBroadcastReceiver();
        if (!isRegistered) {
            registerLocalReceiver();
        }
        //getActivity().registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);

        Intent service = new Intent(getActivity(), StepService.class);
        getActivity().startService(service);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Intent service = new Intent(getActivity(), StepService.class);
        getActivity().startService(service);
        if (!isRegistered) {
            registerLocalReceiver();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Intent service = new Intent(getActivity(), StepService.class);
        getActivity().startService(service);

        if (!isRegistered) {
            registerLocalReceiver();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Intent service = new Intent(getActivity(), StepService.class);
        getActivity().stopService(service);
        if (isRegistered) {
            unregisterLocalReceiver();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Intent service = new Intent(getActivity(), StepService.class);
        getActivity().stopService(service);

        if (isRegistered) {
            unregisterLocalReceiver();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (isRegistered) {
            unregisterLocalReceiver();
        }

    }

    private void registerLocalReceiver() {
        if (!isRegistered) {
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(localtReceiver, intentFilter);
            isRegistered = true;
        }
    }

    private void unregisterLocalReceiver() {
        if (isRegistered) {
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(localtReceiver);
            isRegistered = false;
        }
    }

}
```

And here is the local BR:

```
public class LocalBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static final String STEP_COUNT_UPDATE = "com.example.StayFit.STEP_COUNT_UPDATE";
    public static final String STAY_FIT = "com.example.stayfit";
    private static final int UPDATE_PROGRESS_BAR = 1;

    private int conteggioPassiTotali;
    private float kmPercorsiFloat;
    private int passiRimanenti;
    private int obiettivoPassi;
    private float lunghezzaPassi=1;

    HomeFragment homeFragment;
    DataBaseHandler dbHandler;
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefSC;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        sharedPrefSC = context.getSharedPreferences(STAY_FIT,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String nomeUtente = sharedPrefSC.getString("utenteSessione", "fail");

        if (intent != null && STEP_COUNT_UPDATE.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            obiettivoPassi = dbHandler.getObiettivoPassi(nomeUtente);
            conteggioPassiTotali = intent.getIntExtra("conteggioPassiTotali", 1234);

            kmPercorsiFloat = (conteggioPassiTotali*lunghezzaPassi)/1000;
            passiRimanenti = obiettivoPassi-conteggioPassiTotali;

            String kmPercorsiStr = String.format("%.2f", kmPercorsiFloat);
            String conteggioPassiTotaliStr = String.valueOf(conteggioPassiTotali);

            // Metodo 4 - handler
            // Creating the message for the handler
            Message message = homeFragment.mHandler.obtainMessage(UPDATE_PROGRESS_BAR,conteggioPassiTotali,passiRimanenti,kmPercorsiStr);

            // Sending the handler
            homeFragment.mHandler.sendMessage(message);


        }
    }
}
```

And here the Service class:

```
public class StepService extends Service implements SensorEventListener {

    public static final String STAY_FIT = "com.example.stayfit";

    private boolean primoAvvio;
    private int conteggioPassiTotali;
    private int conteggioPassiAvvio;
    private int conteggioPassiCorrenti;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(STAY_FIT, MODE_PRIVATE);
        primoAvvio = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("primoAvvio", false);

        Log.d("testServoce",Boolean.toString(primoAvvio));

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // Ottengo un riferimento al SensorManager
        SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

        // Ottengo un riferimento al sensore "STEP_COUNTER"
        Sensor stepCounterSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);

        // Verifica presenza del sensore
        if(stepCounterSensor != null) {
            // Lo rendo disponibile:
            sensorManager.registerListener(this, stepCounterSensor,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
                        //Toast.makeText(this, "Congratulazioni, Sensore Presente!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("sensore","sensore presente");
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sensore non presente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("sensore","sensore NON presente");
        }

        // Dice al sistema di riavviare il serivice dopo un crash e di rilasciare gli intent presenti al momento del crash
        return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if(primoAvvio){

            //primoAvvio = false;
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("primoAvvio", false);
            editor.apply();
            conteggioPassiAvvio = (int) event.values[0];
            Log.d("TestPrimoAvvio",Boolean.toString(primoAvvio));
            //Log.d("TestNumeroPassi",Integer.toString(conteggioPassiAvvio));
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, "Rilevato passo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // L'evento del sensore contiene il numero di passi effettuati dall'utente dal reboot
        conteggioPassiCorrenti = (int) event.values[0];
        conteggioPassiTotali = conteggioPassiCorrenti- conteggioPassiAvvio;

        Intent intentStep = new Intent(LocalBroadcastReceiver.STEP_COUNT_UPDATE);
        intentStep.putExtra("conteggioPassiTotali",conteggioPassiTotali);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intentStep);

    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {

    }

}
```

Any suggestion?

I just want to update the circleProgressBar with the current number of step. I don't know if i got a problem with the broadcast or with the code below onSensorChanged

EDIT: just modified the code with update.

Comment: Does your `Service` even get started? I suggest that you first refactor the `Service` into a separate class (not an inner class of your `Fragment`). Make sure that your manifest contains the declaration of your `Service` class.

Comment: @DavidWasser i tryed to separate Service from the HomeFragment class, then to register the receiver i had to remove the constructon inside it. But still doesn't work...

Comment: Does the `Service` get started?

Comment: @DavidWasser yes, it seems to work, infact on the emulator I can see the Toast that I write into the Service. The Service has been started into onCreateView, onCreate and onResume, stopped into onPause and onDestroy(). I think I got some problems with the Broadcast, like it doesn’t receive the int stepCount (conteggioPassiTotali)

Comment: Where/how do you create and register the BroadcastReceiver. Please edit your question and show that code now.

Comment: Add debug logging or use breakpoints in the debugger to see if `onReceive()` is being called and if you can get the "extra" from the `Intent`.

Comment: @DavidWasser updated the code. I use a method to register and one to unregesiter a LocalBroadcast (i think is a way better for an app like mine).

Comment: Is `onReceive()` being called?

Comment: @DavidWasser i don't think. I added a Toast in onReceive() (that should be run on UI, isnt it?) and it doesn't appear on the screen.

Comment: First of all, `Toast` is a horrible way to debug. It is NOT reliable. You should add logging or set breakpoints. Secondly, if you don't think that `onReceive()` is being called, then please verify that `sendBroadcast()` is being called.

Comment: @DavidWasser ok i used some Log.d, and i think that the problem is that onSensorChanged doesn't work. I tryed to shake my devide (that has a STEP_SENSOR) but it has't been called.